# How can I convert multiple column into one column with comma separated value in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation, group-concat

I have a MySql table with **15 Column** and I want to get all the value of **last 12 column into one column** with comma separated.

My table name is like MyTable-

```
User Name     User ID     JAN   FEB   MAR   APR ...
User 01       001         10     30    40    50 ....
User 02       002          44     54   33    90 ..
```

I want the result like -

```
User Name     User ID     Values
User 01       001         '10','30','40','50'
User 02       002         '44','54','33','90'
```

How can i do that into MySql Query.

Thanks for advice.

Comment: you can use concat('''JAN,'','',FEB,'''...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use concat

```
select username,userid,concat(jan,',',feb,',',mar,',',apr) from table
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`CONCAT_WS(separator,str1,str2,...)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws):

```
SELECT
    `User Name`,
    `User ID`,
    CONCAT_WS(',', JAN, FEB, MAR, APR, ...) as `Values`
FROM mytable
```

You can save some bytes of code compared to [`CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat), since you need to write the separator only once.

Comment: @RifatTanjir . . . `concat_ws()` is definitely the better alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You can use concat method as below-

```
SELECT 
`user name`,
`user id`,
CONCAT("'",JAN,"','",FEB,"'" ....) 'Values'
FROM MyTable
```